# Anyone know how to type an useRef?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Im keep getting this error: " Property 'value' does not exist on type 'never' "

```
interface InputProps {
  name: string;
  icon?: ReactElement;
  placeholder?: string;
}

const Input = ({ name, icon: Icon, ...rest }: InputProps) => {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false);
  const [isFilled, setIsFilled] = useState(false);

  const { fieldName, defaultValue, registerField } = useField(name);

  const handleInputFocus = useCallback(() => {
    setIsFocused(true);
  }, []);

  const handleInputBlur = useCallback(() => {
    setIsFocused(false);

    setIsFilled(!!inputRef.current?.value);
  }, []);
```

The error is in this last part: setIsFilled(!!inputRef.current?.value);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provide the type as a generic parameter.

```
useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)
```

This is necesary because the type cannot be inferred from the default value of `null` alone.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.2.3&ssl=10&ssc=51&pln=10&pc=3#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDejUYCiANkiEgHZZwCuAzkgMIrHEBG6A1tvUsgGY8GAZRgoYSOAF84-KBBBwARFAIwlAbgBQW4FSRR+6SQEkKYGjAAK8sHVxa4cCinIAuOHRhQ9Ac21OwGgQFAD8HsjoMCRklDABcGDExgAWEMQAJgbhnt5+2lI6wRRecGYW8AC8cAAUeC7k2EEhHibF2AB0XaqlUq3mljYQdgCUcJUAfA5OxaV6FQLjtAwCADwAEgAqALIAMuWWMeRUEzUUNKwj2o5ws-AA2sB0AGIQaLwZ2AwwJi9vHwBdJa8UTiJA1IzEBhXG53OCPF7AVhIT6eJA-RHIjJA6ogsQSCEsaHXGYhUopFAUDKkA4wV7vey4hjMVgcNCcGo1MaTaZONEY+kfGreGhIGFOKTYe4AmGwsnwClUmkDGAAIWINCgwOZLHYXE53KmOBuTm+v0FDAyhKhYpJfLNmNIVoAhM75pYBB13lBVFRQh0AG4sUXi6RSmUFIA)

---

Another option is to cast `null` to a union where `null` is a member. Then `useRef` *can* infer the right type.

```
useRef(null as HTMLInputElement | null);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.2.3&ssl=10&ssc=60&pln=10&pc=3#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDejUYCiANkiEgHZZwCuAzkgMIrHEBG6A1tvUsgGY8GAZRgoYSOAF84-KBBBwARFAIwlAbgBQW4FSRR+6SQEkKYGjAAK8sHVxa4cCinIAuOHRhQ9Ac21OwGgQFAD8HsjoMCRklDABcGDExgAWEMQAJgbhnt5+2lI6wRRecGYW8AC8cAAUeC7k2EEhHibF2AB0XaqlUq3mljYQdgCUcJUAfA5OxaV6FQLjtAwCNRQ0rHAo9gASACoAsgAy5ZYx5FRwAD7OG8Qj2o5ws-AA2sB0AGIQaLwZ2AwYCYvj8-gBdJa8UTiJA1IzEBgPJ4vODvL7AVhIf6eJBA9GYjIQ6pQsQSOEsRGPGYhUopFAUDKkU4wb6-ezEhjMVgcNCcGo1MaTaZOHF41l-GreGhIJFOKTYV5gpHImnwOkMpkDGAAIWINCgkM5LHYXH5gqmOCeTkBwPFDAy5IRMqpIpt+NIDoAhJ75pYBB1flBVFRQh0AG4saWy6QKpUFIA)

But typically, the `useRef<TypeHere>()` is used because it's cleaner and simpler.